# How do I post a file selected using dojo Uploader to a servlet using Dojo 1.7.5

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, dojo

I have been looking on a proper way to post a file selected using `dojox.form.Uploader` to my servlet, but unable to. There seems to be no proper documentation for dojo neither much of examples / demos / tutorials. Responses will be highly thankful.

My code in JSP is

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="9"><h2>File Upload<br /></h2><h3>To add 800#s using a file</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="9"><input type="file" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Uploader" label ="Browse" multiple="false" id="uploader" onchange="check();" uploadOnSelect="true" url="/MyProject/app/ActionRequestHandlerServlet"/>
        <div id="files" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.uploader.FileList" uploaderId="uploader" ></div>
    </td>
</tr>`
```

The Javascript code includes the below

```
function check() {
    alert(dijit.byId("uploader").value);
    formPostObject.file = dijit.byId("uploader").value;
    sendFile();
}

function sendFile() {
    dojo.io.iframe.send({
        url: "/MyProject/app/ActionRequestHandlerServlet", // Replace with yours
        method: "post",
        handleAs: "text",
        form: dojo.byId("uploader"),
        load: function(response, ioArgs) {
            console.log("Upload OK", response, ioArgs);
            return response;
        },
        error: function(response, ioArgs) {
            console.log("Upload FAILED!!!", response, ioArgs);
            return response;
        }
    });
}
```

The above code does not give me any response. There sysout statements in my servlet are alsonot prited. This gives an JS error on dojo.js -> 'length' is null or not an object. Where as I am not using length anywhere in my code. 
Request you to please help me out with this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi, could you post a standalone HTML file that can be used as is to reproduce the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what has worked for me using dojo 1.6 but that should make no difference in 1.7 
the key was that enctype="multipart/form-data" requires Servlet 3.0 to actually work. 
Also there is a annotation that has to be added to the servlet @MultipartConfig

--- HTML --

```
dojo.require("dojox.form.Uploader");
dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.FileList");
dojo.require("dojox.embed.Flash");
if(dojox.embed.Flash.available){
  dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.plugins.Flash");
}else{
  dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.plugins.IFrame");
}
</script>

<body>
<form method="post" action="ReadInputFilesServlet" id="myForm"
               enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 <fieldset>
    <input name="uploadedfile" multiple="true" type="file" id="uploader"
      dojoType="dojox.form.Uploader" label="Select Some Files" >
       <input type="submit" label="Submit" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" />
    <div id="files" dojoType="dojox.form.uploader.FileList"
                    uploaderId="uploader"></div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

--- in servlet  --

```
@MultipartConfig(location="C:\\TMP_FILES", fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024, maxFileSize=1024*1024*5, maxRequestSize=1024*1024*5*5)

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Collection <Part> files = request.getParts();
        Iterator <Part> iter = files.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Part part = iter.next();

            String filename = getFileName(part);

            System.out.println("File "+ filename);

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new              InputStreamReader(part.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            }
            rd.close();
        }

    }

public static String getFileName(Part filePart)
{
    String header = filePart.getHeader("content-disposition");
    for(String headerPart : header.split(";"))
    {
        if(headerPart.trim().startsWith("filename"))
        {
            return headerPart.substring(headerPart.indexOf('=') + 1).trim()
                             .replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```